# How to distribute a desktop app built with Electron, Node.js and Python

Tags: express, electron, impala

I have recently built a desktop app using Electron and Express.js, and I also used python-shell in Node.js to call a python module. Specifically, the Express server will call the python module which sends SQL queries to Impala, and get the query result from it, then transmit it to the front-end.

It works well, but I wonder how to distribute this app? Obviously the python-shell module is not applicable without python environment. Any suggestions? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have two possibilities:

1. Distribute a Python Installer along your Installation
2. Port your Python module to a native executable, native node module, or plain JS in the Electron app itself.